# XAMPP - SSL Certificate. Broken HTTPS

Tags: php, apache, ssl, xampp, sha1

I was trying to get a SSL Certificate for my website using XAMPP. I am doing exactly what they tell me to do using this tutorial http://robsnotebook.com/xampp-ssl-encrypt-passwords.
For some reason I get this error https://i.gyazo.com/5da7549ca6baaed8ce96d5c55c9dd7e4.png
It says that "The page is insecure (Broken https).

This is my httpd-vhosts.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
        DocumentRoot "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\xampp\htdocs"
        ServerName myproject
        SSLEngine on
        SSLCertificateFile "conf/ssl.crt/server.crt"
        SSLCertificateKeyFile "conf/ssl.key/server.key"
        <Directory "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\xampp\htdocs">
            Options All
            AllowOverride All
            Require all granted
        </Directory>
    </VirtualHost>
```

And I've did everything they told me to do on the tutorial, please tell me why this error appears..

Answer (score 0):

That SSL Certificate has outdated certificate chain called SHA1. SHA1 was announced in late 1995 and it does not fit with [current security standards according to NIST](http://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/Legacy/SP/nistspecialpublication800-131a.pdf) (National Institute of Standard and Technology), so almost browser and Certificate Authorities have stopped supporting SHA1 certificates. I suggest you to ask your provider to issue SSL Certificate with latest SHA2 encryption which is accepted by most of browsers. I would like to give you some reference links which will guide you in detail:

https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/srd/2013/11/12/security-advisory-2880823-recommendation-to-discontinue-use-of-sha-1/

https://security.googleblog.com/2014/09/gradually-sunsetting-sha-1.html

https://blog.mozilla.org/security/2014/09/23/phasing-out-certificates-with-sha-1-based-signature-algorithms/